How do I set up a context filter to use transliterated taxonomy terms in URLs instead of their original names?
I have a question.
1) Question:
In Drupal 9, I am creating a Views based page with a context filter that takes a taxonomy term from the URL. For example:
/my-view/%[product-type]
The taxonomy terms are in the "Product Type" vocabulary and are translated into several languages ​​(for example, the term "insurance" has translations: Versicherung in German and Assurance in French).
I would expect the URL to work for each language, for example:

/de/my-view/versicherung
/fr/my-view/assurance

But it seems that the context filter only works with the original (source) name of the term, and the translations are ignored.
Is it possible to configure Drupal so that the URL uses a transliteration of the term (for example, /my-view/%kholodnyy instead of the original name)?
If so, how can I do this?
Views itself has a path with an argument that should be taken from the Latin alphabet of the term Path:/my-view/%
